# Android Java error handling XML file

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm using SAX and XML reader to read XML weather info from the web and it works fine if the page exists. But if for instance the user inputs an invalid city, zip etc the XML page that gets read from is empty and the app force closes with nullpointerexception. The area that generates the error is here right at open inputstream. Any suggestions?:

```
            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser sp = null;
            try {
                sp = spf.newSAXParser();
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            /* Get the XMLReader of the SAXParser we created. */
            XMLReader xr = null;
            try {
                xr = sp.getXMLReader();
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            /* Create a new ContentHandler and apply it to the XML-Reader*/
            WeatherHandler myExampleHandler = new WeatherHandler();
            xr.setContentHandler(myExampleHandler);

            /* Parse the xml-data from our URL. */
            try {     
                xr.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
                    parsedWeatherDataSet =
                        myExampleHandler.getParsedData();               
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return parsedWeatherDataSet.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about not catching away all exceptions, but handle some of them?

Having an incorrect URL is quite common. Make the appropriate checks and bring up a message box...

Comment: sorry for stating the obvious

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting these over the web, then you're probably using HTTP requests, which have response codes that tell you whether the request succeeded. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes and do what you're already doing if it's a 200, and let the user know in an appropriate way if it's something else (in this case, it might be 404)

Comment: Hi it's not a 404. e.g here's an example http://a7789773896.api.wxbug.net/getForecastRSS.aspx?ACode=A7789773896&zipCode=10d303&UnitType=0&OutputType=1

Comment: That should be a 404, or maybe a 204 (no content). That's badly design, frankly, because it would be really useful in exactly this situation if they used the response codes. I guess you just need to check whether the content is the empty string (or all-whitespace) before trying to parse it.

Comment: How do I check before? I try after but get the nullpointerexception

Comment: Get the content that is delivered over the network from `url.openStream()` and put it in a String (or maybe there's another `CharSequence` that's more appropriate...) and check if there is any content or not. If there is, parse it as XML. If not, display a "no data available" message or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

Rather than:
return parsedWeatherDataSet.toString(); 
at the bottom

I made a string in the try portion and returned that instead. That solved it. Cheers for all the suggestions